Deploying a proxy for the smart contract using hardhat ethers is not working
I am able to compile the smart contract successfully, which generates the ABI and bytecode for the contract as expected.
Below is my deployContract function that gets the ABI and bytecode for the respective smart contract and uses Hardhat upgrades proxy to deploy the contract:
async deployContract(contractName: string) {
  const { abi, bytecode } = this.getContractCode(contractName);
  const wallet = await this.getDeployWallet();

  const ContractRequest = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);
  await proxy.waitForDeployment();
}

However, I am encountering the following error during deployment:

Error: The requested contract was not found. Make sure the source code is available for compilation

I have confirmed that the contract compiles successfully and generates the ABI and bytecode as expected. Here are some additional points about my setup:

The function getContractCode(contractName) retrieves the compiled ABI and bytecode for the given contract name.
I am using Hardhat for compilation and deployment, along with the
ethers.js library.
The deployment wallet is correctly initialised and connected.

Despite this, the error indicates that the requested contract cannot be found.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue. Could this be related to the Hardhat configuration, the contract factory initialization, or something else?
Additionally:

How can I verify if the correct ABI and bytecode are being passed to
the ethers.ContractFactory?
Is there a better way to debug the deployment process in this setup?

Any help or guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
